# ¿Como instalo/agrego OpenOCD en Visual Studio Code? ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc, cmd

Tengo OpenOCD instalado en mi maquina y al hacer `openocd --version`
en el cmd de windows (aplicacion) me devuelve la version del OpenOCD y funciona bien pero en el cmd que utilizo en ASP.NET con `ProcessStarInfo` al mandarle 'openocd --version' muestra `"openocd" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.` ¿Como podria solucionarlo para que el OpenOCD funcione desde el ASP.NET o Visual Studio Core?
En ASP.NET tengo esto:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(cmdModel value)
        {
            string txtcmd = value.Txtcmd;
            string resultcmd = value.Resultcmd;
            
            var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"cmd.exe", $"/C {txtcmd}")
            {
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true
            };

            var query = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo };
            query.Start();
            query.WaitForExit();
        
            var result = query.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd().ToString(); //respuesta de la consola
            ViewBag.resultcmd = result; //devolver la respuesta a la vista
            
            var output = query.StandardError.ReadToEnd().ToString(); //respuesta de error en la consola
            ViewBag.outputcmd = output; //devuelve la respuesta de error en el cmd a la vista

            Console.WriteLine(result);
            return View("Index", new cmdModel());
        }
```

En la vista del `localhost:5001` solo hay un textbox para enviar comandos al cmd con su respectivo boton de `enviar` y un textarea donde se muestra el resultado o error que devuelva el cmd.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! mmm aca hay algo raro.. vos queres que tu servidor, que deberia ser independiente de la pc en que este, habra un proceso OCD del lado del servidor... pero tu pagina esta en un entorno seguro, que es muy probable que no tenga permisos para ejecutar eso (y no deberia)... que es lo que estas tratando de hacer?

Comment: Trato de que el cmd que abre la clase ProcessStarInfo pueda reconocer comandos de OpenOCD como `openocd --version` ya que el cmd de mi cimputadora normal si puede

Comment: Claro.. pero esto es asp.net... estas dentro de un servidor web con un proceso particular... no tiene permisos para cualquier cosa.. y las cosas que haces las haces en el servidor.. no suena a algo que quieras hacer desde una pagina web...

Comment: Tal vez si explicas mejor tu escenario podamos ayudarte mas..